# create link for URL-based text field in content type

Tags: entities, navigation

Drupal 7 question: In my Events content type, I have a text field called RSVP URL. On the event page, it currently displays as

**RSVP URL:** http://example.com

However, I would like it to be a link, displaying like so:

**RSVP URL:** http://example.com

I'm not seeing a way to do this, except perhaps via adding the [Link module](https://www.drupal.org/project/link)?, but I'm a newbie who's never even installed a module before, and I'm wondering if there's another built-in way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Click on edit in front of your link field in your content type's manage field tab.

[image]

You need to change Text processing option to filtered Text.

[image]

Then while adding this content type just type the URL with HTML tag.

[image]

I hope this solves your problem without installing a module.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like the simpliest way to do that will be to install the [linke field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/link) directly from the web.

To do so :

- Go to **admin/modules** ;
- Clic on [Install new module](http://localhost/drupal7/admin/modules/install) ;
- **Open a new tab**. Paste link module link and go. A page displays with the **description** of the module ;
- At the bottom of that page, **Copy the link to the file** (zip or tar.gz one) which is [this one](https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/link-7.x-1.4.zip) (this one is the zip one) ;
- **Go to the drupal** (Install new module) **page**. Paste that link on the *Install from url* field and hit Install. Wait 'till it finished in a few seconds ;
- Clic on *Enable newly added*.... ;
- Search for the link field module by scrolling. Clic on install. Wait untill it finished in a few time ;

And you can go back to your content type in order to create that new link field with the wright type.

Does that help ?

Comment: My apologies for never responding way back when (I was such a newbie back then, and was also afraid of inadvertently revealing how much our team at the moment lacked anybody who could fix things if I did the module installation wrong, let alone worse fragilities the site had then, haha). While I did use the other answer in my case, I appreciated the step-by-step module enabling instructions back then (fortunately these days mostly doing composer+drush in D8), and no doubt your answer was useful to others, including those who didn't want to require their content editors write HTML!